# Should questions that don't have up voted answers display 0 answers on the home page?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, unanswered-questions

The definition of an unanswered question is a question that doesn't have an accepted or up voted answer. However, on the home page, these "unanswered questions" show up as having some number of answers. What would the impact be of either showing the number of up voted answers or the number of non-negative (>= 0) scored answers instead of the number of things posted as answers?

On one hand, people looking for solutions may not enter the question. But if nothing has attracted an accept or an up vote, is that a problem? No one has indicated that an answer is good enough, so it may effectively not have an answer.

On the other hand, it may help people with answers be more willing to click on through if they aren't getting to the list of questions with an "unanswered" filter.

Thoughts? Impact?

Comment: No, this will be too misleading.